# How to set hyperlink text in the "Modern" version of OneNote

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, microsoft-onenote

Note this question is specific to the "Modern"/"Metro"/"Windows Store" version of OneNote.

I am trying to accomplish a very simple task (at least - it used to be simple).  I simply want to set the text of a hyperlink.  In the desktop version, it was simply a right-click away.

In the "Modern" version of OneNote, I cannot find any way to set the text of a hyperlink for a url.  The radial meanu appears to be useless for this purpose, and right-clicking simply brings up the bottom app bar with similarly useless (for this purpose) functionality.

How to I set the display text of a hyperlink in "Modern" OneNote?